# Проблема отображение страниц в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Проблема с Google Chrome.

1. Не открывает страницы государственых учереждений (зона gov.ua)
   Выдает сообщение:

   > Подключение не защищенно.
   >   Злоумышленники могут похитить ваши данные с сайта ..........
2. Некорректно работает в личном кабинете bitrix.

Компьютер:

1. Проверял на вирусы (ничего не найдено)
2. Chrome версия 67.0.3396.99
3. В DNS настройках указаны сервера Google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)
4. Данные сервера пингуются без проблем.
5. Все расширения отключены.

Установил Mozilla Firefox последнюю версию все работает никаких проблем нет.

Google Chrome несколько раз удалял и устанавливал результата нет.

Кто-то может помочь в решении вопроса?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Проверьте доступ к http://rada.gov.ua/ Если работает, то скажите конкретные проблемные сайты

Comment: Здравствуйте.
На rada.gov.ua в Chrome зашел, правда сказал что незащищенное соединение. 
На сайт bank.gov.ua не зашел выдало сообщение в Хроме: Подключение не защищенно. Злоумышленники могут похитить ваши данные с сайта.
В Mozilla Firefox на bank.gov.ua зашел, нормально никаких сообщений не было. (Mozilla показала что bank.gov.ua защищенное соединение)

Comment: Смотрите сертификат и путь сертификации. Должно быть так https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKefR.png если не так, то ищите, кто у вас подменяет сертификаты

Comment: Anton, хорошо я это сделаю.
Вопрос, мне надо будет для каждого сайта где выдается сообщение об ошибке вручную вот, так добавлять сертификат?

Comment: Я не сказал добавлять сертификаты. Я сказал посмотреть, что у вас отображается. И если сертификат отличен от того, что показал я, то искать у себя вирус, который эти сертификаты заменяет

Comment: Сертификат можно опубликовать в тексте запроса